# Check values of loop to see if ANY match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In ruby, I would do something like:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.any? {|a| a == 1}
=> true
```

Although, instead of an array, I am going up against a hash

```
var shop_products = {"607":607};
```

I have a checkbox loop and I want to check against all currently checked boxes for when checkboxes are both checked and unchecked to then see if there is a matching value and disable/able and hide/show a button if so.

code: https://jsfiddle.net/mk879vu2/7/

As @Mark Meyer mentioned, some can help but is there a way to use this against a hash or an alt for hashes?

I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/jq9sgp58/

Maybe I am using this wrong?

My issue right now is when a checkbox is unchecked, it sees that the value is the "correct" one, but it isn't displaying the button when I uncheck.  I'm doing something wrong in the conditional somehow.

In the jsfiddle I have all of the inputs but I only want one of the buttons (of the 2) to appear when a record with specific parameters is checked (in the example this is value=607, this can be any amount but in the example I have it as 1 record/input).  But when I uncheck and the 607 is left alone as the only checked input, it runs the hide/disable and not the show.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/2kaegb59/

The `.some` seemed like the way to get it done but i couldn't get it to work with the hash.  I'm sure it's possible.  Although, I ended up just checking for an undefined through the hash instead of trying to match up the check value with the hash value and it is likely unnoticeably faster.

```
   for (var check of checked_checkboxes_check) {
      if (shop_products[check.value] === undefined) {
        print_submit.hide().prop("disabled", true);
        break;
      } else {
        print_submit.show().prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for [`#array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let a = [1,2,3]

console.log(a.some(n => n === 1)) // true

console.log(a.some(n => n === 4)) //false
```

Comment: This looks like the right direction but how can I use this against the hash values? https://jsfiddle.net/jq9sgp58/